# Getting a Report from a XML

Tags: php, css, xml, xslt

I know that i can XSLT, but my tags are just like `<RepAux:DetAuxFol>` or `<RepAux:ComprNal>` for example. Then when i wanna CSS:

```
RepAux:RepAuxFol{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%; }

RepAux:ComprNal{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30pt;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I'm not able to visualize my XML. Or maybe some other option have to do "like-a-report" to show to the user.

Thanks for your time, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The namespace prefix separator in CSS is `|`, `<RepAux:DetAuxFol>` would be referenced as `RepAux|DetAuxFol` in the CSS selector. You can attach a CSS or XSLT into the XML and browsers might render it. Or you use PHP and a XSLT to transform the XML into an HTML output.

Comment: It was my bad. it was working, but i got no text between the open and start tag. I guess what i need is to show the tag values, i got something like this

`<RepAux:ComprNal UUID_CFDI="847ABD84-E24C-4DE8-9118-0D22E85B0F89" MontoTotal="4860.18" RFC="TGP941129IX2" MetPagoAux="0" Moneda="MXN" TipCamb="0.0000"/>`

Comment: I've been serched and find this piece of code to try to solve my problem: 

`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(parent::*),'> ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'=&#x22;',.,'&#x22;&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`